# Как занести несколько слов (текстов) в функцию if?

Tags: python

У меня не получается сделать два варианта ответа в функции `if`: программа должна принимать одно из двух занесенных слов, но она принимает то первое слово, то второе.

```
a = input("введите слово Да")
if a == ('Да', 'да'):
    print("Проверено.")
```

Answer (score 4):

Для этого в python можно использовать in:

```py
a = input("введите слово Да")
if a in ('Да', 'да'):
    print("Проверенно.")
```

Но в вашем случае можно использовать `.lower()` что заменит все заглавные буквы на строчные:

```py
a = input("введите слово Да")
if a.lower() == 'да':
    print("Проверенно.")
```

Comment: Благодарствую за ответ. Я занимаюсь питоном больше полтора месяца и переучиваю базу

Comment: @FainLight, отметьте этот ответ как [**принятый**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) (галка напротив ответа).